# Need to set Auto layout constraint use code for my UIButton at bottom-centre

Tags: ios, uibutton, constraints

***This is my updated question !***

I have searched many tutorial & sites for setting Auto layout constraints to set my UIButton at bottom-centre of my view controller.I use code to create uiButton and i have set position,but typically i can see my uiButton are positioning in different place  in different simulator(4S,5,6,INFACT ON MY OWN DEVICE).i need to set my uibutton at bottom-centre [Like this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rflfgfhy8sd4wvp/DMNASDDJA.png?dl=0)

I am new to ios ,so can't able to set constraint for my UIButton.And this is my UIButton code:

```
self->closeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self->closeBtn.frame = CGRectMake(260, 30, 50, 28);
self->closeBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
self->closeBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self->closeBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:179.0/255.0 green:179.0/255.0 blue:179.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
[self->closeBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self->closeBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.75];
[self->closeBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self->closeBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0]];
[self.view addSubview:self->closeBtn];
[self->closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(closeBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self->closeBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint * c_1 =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self->closeBtn
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                      multiplier:1.0 constant:60];
NSLayoutConstraint * c_2 =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self->closeBtn
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      multiplier:1.0 constant:-1*60];



NSLayoutConstraint * equal_w = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self->closeBtn
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:nil
                                                            attribute:0
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:70];
NSLayoutConstraint * equal_h = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self->closeBtn
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:nil
                                                            attribute:0
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:28];
[self.view addConstraints:@[c_1,c_2]];
[self->closeBtn addConstraints:@[equal_w,equal_h]];
```

This above code is set for at top-right.so i have changed that to bottom,centre but i can't able to see my button.i need my button [Like this image button position](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rflfgfhy8sd4wvp/DMNASDDJA.png?dl=0) Not able to set constraint to place my uibutton position at in same place.Kindly any one can help me out to solve my problem

Comment: Don't manipulate the frame when using auto layout.  Just adjust the constraints.  You will need to search for adding constraints programmatically in iOS.  This will give you plenty of tuts to follow.  But you need to add some constraints, like pin to bottom, center on superview, width and height.

Comment: i have updated my post.still my code not able to set .please any one help me out.i new to ios

Comment: I think you have the first two backwards.  You want to add all constraints to the button, not the view.  And don't use the right or left because that will change on each device.  Use center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have check your code.Replace this below code with your code .You can get your button at position as you required

```
UIView *superview = self.view;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self->closeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self->closeBtn.frame = CGRectMake(260, 100, 50, 28);
    self->closeBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self->closeBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    self->closeBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:179.0/255.0 green:179.0/255.0 blue:179.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    [self->closeBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self->closeBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.75];
    [self->closeBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self->closeBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0]];
    [self.view addSubview:self->closeBtn];
    [self->closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(closeBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self->closeBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint * c_1 =[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:self->closeBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:superview attribute:
                               NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:-7.5f];


    NSLayoutConstraint * c_2 =[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:self->closeBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:
                               NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.85f constant:0.0f];


    NSLayoutConstraint * equal_w = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self->closeBtn
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:nil
                                                                attribute:0
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:50];
    NSLayoutConstraint * equal_h = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self->closeBtn
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:nil
                                                                attribute:0
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:28];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[c_1,c_2]];
    [self->closeBtn addConstraints:@[equal_w,equal_h]];
```

Hope this helpful.Please learn some tutorial for auto layout.sure this concepts are very helpful for making App ...